# Get param 'Link' in the Header with Guzzle

Tags: php, rest, guzzle, guzzle6

I am using a third-party API. And the API has a pagination to navigate through the data. In the header I get the Link parameter where the next, previous, first and last are located, but when I get the `Link` param with `Guzzle` I get a `*String*`.

```
....
$responseAPI = $httpClient->get($uri);

$linkHeader = $responseAPI->getHeader("Link");
....
```

I got:

```
'http://next.com"; rel="next", http://next.com"; rel="prev"'
```

Is there a way to access the `Link` with the 'rel' keyword? Like it's an array? or in some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_header($response->getHeader('Link'))` see the [docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html):

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    
$response = $client->get('https://httpbin.org/response-headers?Link=http://next.com?3;rel="next",http://next.com?1;rel="prev"');

print_r(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\parse_header($response->getHeader('Link')));
```